# Undefined Reference using Python

Tags: python

```
def get_list():
    print('enter the list of integers on a single line, separated by comma, enter to end: \n')
    num1 = [int(i) for i in input().split(',')]
    return num1

def calculate(n1, n2, length):
    n3=list()
    for i in range(0, length(n1)):
        n3.append(n1[i]+n2[i])

num1 = get_list()
print(num1)
num2 = get_list()
print(num2)
num3 = calculate(num1, num2, length)   
print("the new list is: ", num3)
```

Im getting a undefined reference error can can't figure out how to get this code working

Comment: Can you post the full error instead of your summary of the error?

Comment: This happens every time someone new asks questions, but we'll say it again. Please include the full stack trace : ) Otherwise only you know where the error happened, and we're guessing.

Comment: Where do you define the `length` passed to `calculate`? Hint: You don't.

Answer (score 0):

In the following line the variable `length` is never defined.

```
num3 = calculate(num1, num2, length)
```

In fact, you do not need that variable in the first place

```
def calculate(n1, n2):
    return [i+j for i,j in zip(n1, n2)]

num3 = calculate(num1, num2)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is `length` supposed to be in this function?

```
def calculate(n1, n2, length):
    n3=list()
    for i in range(0, length(n1)):
        n3.append(n1[i]+n2[i])
```

This is where type annotations are useful; even the process of writing them can help you think about how your code works (or how it doesn't).  Based on the way you use these variables, I'd figure the types would be:

```
from typing import Callable, List

def calculate(
    n1: List[int], 
    n2: List[int], 
    length: Callable[[List[int]], int]
) -> None:
    n3: List[int] = list()
    for i in range(0, length(n1)):
        n3.append(n1[i]+n2[i])
```

Some interesting things about this function that we can quickly infer from the types of its parameters and its return value:

1. `length` is a function that you call on a list, and you get a number out of it (presumably the length).  That sounds a lot like the built-in `len` function -- would you ever want to use something other than that?
2. This function doesn't return anything, which means that this:

```
print("the new list is: ", num3)
```

is always going to print something like `the new list is: None`.  Is that what you mean for it to do?

A version of this function that doesn't need the `length` argument and actually returns the calculated list would be:

```
from typing import List

def calculate(
    n1: List[int], 
    n2: List[int], 
) -> List[int]:
    n3: List[int] = []
    for i in range(len(n1)):
        n3.append(n1[i]+n2[i])
    return n3
```

Or, writing this exact same `for` loop as a comprehension instead of creating an empty list and appending to it:

```
from typing import List

def calculate(
    n1: List[int], 
    n2: List[int], 
) -> List[int]:
    return [n1[i]+n2[i] for i in range(len(n1))]
```